# Limiting probability percentage of irrelevant image in CNN

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am training a cnn model with five classes using keras library. Using model.predict function i get prediction percentage of the classes. My problem is for a image which doesn't belong to these classes and completely irrelevant, the predict class still predicts the percentages according to the classes.

How do I prevent it? How do I identify it as irrelevant?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a softmax activation on your last layer to generate the probabilities for each class. By definition, the sum of the outputs from the softmax activation must add up to 1. Therefore, it is impossible for the neural net to say that the image does not belong to any of your classes, with your current setup.

There are two potential ways you could address this:

1. Add another class that represents "other" or "unknown" objects (so you have 6 classes).
2. Add another output to your neural net (or train a completely independent neural net) that does binary classification on whether or not the image is in one of the 5 classes. That way, if your secondary output says that the image is not in the 5 classes, you can ignore the softmax output.

In both cases, you will need to augment your dataset with images that do not fall in your 5 classes.

Comment: Thanks Swapnil. I was thinking about the first approach, creating an others class and augmenting with irrelevant images. Then if  this class has the highest prediction percentage, then just output irrelevant message. Pl let me know your views

Comment: Yes, that seems like a reasonable approach. Try to get a diverse set of images for your irrelevant image class so that it doesn't learn a false correlation in the irrelevant images.