# How to classify a Binary Classifier to a classifier with 3 labels?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm working on a model which takes 2 labels(say A and B) as input. But, there might be a possibility that the output that needs to be predicted is neither A nor B, and hence I want to predict can't say. Could you plz guide me how to do that?

Also, guidance with some code snippets would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question over here: [Limiting probability percentage of irrelevant image in CNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322703/limiting-probability-percentage-of-irrelevant-image-in-cnn/62327198#62327198)

The difference in your question is that you are doing binary classification instead of multi-class classification, as in their question. To predict unknown classes, as I mentioned there, you need to change your last layer to have an output of dimension 3. Then, apply a softmax activation to that (instead of using a sigmoid, which you might be currently using), which makes it such that the probabilities of each class add up to 1.

I don't know what framework you are using to build your model, so I can't provide relevant code snippets.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Swapnil, and apologies for the lack of information. I'm creating a random forest model, on a data set with just 2 classes. I just want to add the third class!   Also, will it now be possible for you to add some code snippet? Because I've brainstormed on this alot, but I haven't found any good solution.